# How to read xml file?

Tags: xml, vba, xmldom

Sample XML file (insert path):

```
<FilePath>
<TemplatePath> "C:\Users\test.txt" </TemplatePath>
</FilePath>
```

I am trying to take the value of TemplatePath.

I get

> run-time error '91'

```vb
Sub testxml()

Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
oXMLFile.Load ("C:\Users\Config.xml")

Set prova = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("//FilePath/TemplatePath").item(0).Text
Debug.Print prova
```

I cannot find proper documentation. Microsoft learn doesn't explain well.

Comment: try `set xXMLFile = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument60")`. Is a namespace declared in config.xml?

Comment: If needing only to extract the tag value, you may use RegEx, too.

Comment: Is there only one such tag or many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set prova =`  is incorrect as `.Text` returns a string not an object reference, instead:

```
dim text as string
text = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("//FilePath/TemplatePath").Item(0).Text
```

Alternatively if there is always a single `TemplatePath` element simply:

```
debug.print oXMLFile.SelectSingleNode("//FilePath/TemplatePath").Text
```

If there are multiple nodes, loop them:

```
Set prova = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("//FilePath/TemplatePath")
   
For Each node In prova
    debug.print node.Text
Next node
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find the [XML DOM Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757828(v=vs.85)) described in MSDN.

To read the content you may use the following code (without item[0]):

```
oXMLFile.SelectSingleNode("//FilePath/TemplatePath").Text
```